# Converting non-stationary to stationary

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I have one data it is **not stationary**. I'm trying to make it **stationary**.
I tried log transformation, BoxCox transformation, lag(1, 2 and 3) differences.
No use of these transformations and differencing.

I used **adf test** to test stationary in R.
Can anybody tell is there any other method to make it stationary.

**data:**

```
6.668
5.591
4.734
3.493
3.235
3.968
2.64
2.885
3.045
3.579
5.463
5.458
5.758
5.931
5.731
6.799
9.568
9.11
6.571
8.528
15.11
13.956
16.46
19.599
27.281
39.928
56.284
67.565
106.399
104.229
100.686
141.755
164.447
```

Comment: What happens if you try `diff(log(data))`? `diff(diff(log(data)))`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not respond to my comment, so to make the point, if you try

```
> require(tseries)
> adf.test(diff(diff(log(data))))
```

then you get the response

```
        Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  diff(diff(log(data))) 
Dickey-Fuller = -5.1371, Lag order = 3, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary 

Warning message:
In adf.test(diff(diff(log(data)))) : p-value smaller than printed p-value
```

Comment: Another question I have,
I used ARIMA(2,0,1) for diff(diff(log(data))) data.
and predicted next 3 years. Predicted values are;
0.13799588
0.05763208
-0.02169350
How to convert back this values to real values in R?

Thank you in advance..

Comment: To reverse `diff` try `cumsum` or `diffinv`.  To reverse `log` try `exp`.