# How to make the series stationary

Tags: r, time-series

I have a series as below:

```
dat <- c(9, 8, 10, 10, 11, 12, 16, 20, 18, 18, 21, 22, 25, 14)
```

It would be a great help if you can share how to make the series stationary. I have tried `diff` and `log` transformation, however noting is of any help till now. Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test is still insignificant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: converting non-stationary to stationary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192428/r-converting-non-stationary-to-stationary)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your data stationary for example by combining `CoxBox` with `diff`, like this:

```
    # getting package for CoxBox transformations
    library(RxODE)      

    # setting up your data
    dat <- c(9, 8, 10, 10, 11, 12, 16, 20, 18, 18, 21, 22, 25, 14)

    # checking the stationarity
    adf.test(diff(coxBox(dat, lambda=5)))
    #   Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test
    # data:  diff(coxBox(dat, lambda = 5))
    # Dickey-Fuller = -3.8838, Lag order = 2, p-value = 0.02973
    # alternative hypothesis: stationary

    adf.test(diff(coxBox(dat, lambda=4)))
    # Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test
    # data:  diff(coxBox(dat, lambda = 4))
    # Dickey-Fuller = -3.7048, Lag order = 2, p-value = 0.04251
    # alternative hypothesis: stationary

    adf.test(diff(coxBox(dat, lambda=-3)))
    # Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test
    # data:  diff(coxBox(dat, lambda = -3))
    # Dickey-Fuller = -4.2585, Lag order = 2, p-value = 0.01424
    # alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

And an inverse of the Box-Cox can be done like [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bimixt/versions/1.0/topics/boxcox.inv):

```
library(bimixt)
dat <- c(9, 8, 10, 10, 11, 12, 16, 20, 18, 18, 21, 22, 25, 14) # Original data
dat_cb <- coxBox(dat, lambda=3)                                # data after Cox Box transformation with lambda=3
dat_inv_cb <- boxcox.inv(dat_cb, lambda=3)                     # data after INVERSE Cox Box transformation with lambda=3

dat_inv_cb
#  [1]  9  8 10 10 11 12 16 20 18 18 21 22 25 14
```

Comment: Dear Oka, Thanks a lot for your valuable information. I am very new to coxBox. After I transform and forecast the series, may I know your suggestion how to revert back the data into original set? Just like InvBoxCox for Boxcox, do we have something here?

Comment: Dear Pradosh, I didn´t found the procedure for inverse transformation in `RxODE`, but it looks like you can do it with `bimixt` package. I added that to the answer.